# Connecticut Distance Based Non-Compete Clause

Tags: workplace, non-compete

In the state of Connecticut, what are reasonable conditions for the distance a worker must not compete within as per a contract put into place when employment begins.

Do things become different depending on the expertise required such as those requiring specialised schooling?

Answer (score 2):

Defining "reasonableness" is pretty much always going to be a fact-intensive inquiry in a non-compete case. The answer can depend on lots of things, including the nature of the work, industry standards, the size of the market, the training/experience/education required of employees, and so on.